# VirtualBox - Transfer file from guest to host machine

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I'm working on malware analysis using VirtualBox.

I have created Windows 7 VM, in which I am going to inspect the malware.
I would like to send back to the host machine the files and data from the analysis before I destroy the infected machine.

The "problem" is:

1. I uninstalled the "virtual box guest addition" so the malware won't suspect that it is in a VM, so a shared folder isn't an option
2. I have disabled the network connections for the guest machine (host-only), as a safety measure.

What are the other options to transfer files from the guest to the host machine?
What is the safest?

Comment: I would use the passthrough thumbdrive option to plug/unplug a thumbdrive between host and guest

Comment: This question is off topic on Security SE.

Comment: _"Uninstalled guest additions so the malware won't suspect"_ this would lower your host's attack surface, but there are other easy (more common?)  ways to detect a VM, such as looking for the virtual hardware.

Comment: @mentallurg Hey, Can you explain me why please? I was thinkging really hard on what SE site this question belong, and finally I decided here it fits the most. Was I worng?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I gusse you right, but as long as the malware executing itself, I am happy, and so far this is the case.

Comment: @TimothyWong Thank you, good idea. That's the first idea that came into my mind, wanted to know if it the right way, and if it's (somehow) safe.

Comment: @RanEldan "how to configure virtualization software" is not a security question, even if that's the reason you're asking. That would probably fit better on Super User. Asking about the risks of various methods, given your intent and threat model, may be on topic here.

Comment: @RanEldan: What is on topic is described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You question is mainly about how to use VirtualBox and that's why is off topic.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's kind of difficult to do plug and play malware nowadays (at least last I heard), so your thumbdrive should be fine. I also would agree that SE might be off topic -- the question seems to fall in either Stackoverflow or Super User

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this:   https://superuser.com/questions/1677220/virtualbox-transfer-files-from-guest-to-host-machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox - Transfer files from guest to host machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1677220/virtualbox-transfer-files-from-guest-to-host-machine)